# How to publish a postgis layer to geoserver?

Tags: postgis, geoserver, postgresql-9.6

Now my geoserver is on the amazon instance and the postgresql is on the other Amazon RDS. I have try the way provided by official document, but it always show the errors as following:
  "Caused by: org.apache.commons.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Cannot create 
    PoolableConnectionFactory ..."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the external server to the [pg_hba.conf](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file of your PostgreSQL Server to allow the connection. After that, reload/restart postgres.

```
host       database  user  address  auth-method  [auth-options]
hostssl    database  user  address  auth-method  [auth-options]
```